How to fix significant inprecision in converting RDS to ETRS89 with RDNAPTRANS2018 implementation in C#?
I am attempting to convert RDS coordinates to ETRS89. I will have to do this thousands of times a minute for which reason I am creating the implementation myself.
To do this I have gotten the RDNAPTRANS2018 and implemented the formula in C#. This code is at the bottom of the question. However, when executing the code I find each coordinate has about ~100-1000 meters difference from the actual RDS coordinates. An example:
//Given RDS
RD-X: 74402
RD-Y: 448670

//Calculated ETRS89
POINT (52.018499953545344 4.209861310427128)

//RDS of calculated ETRS89
RD-X: 74186
RD-Y: 448449

I have considered there may be an issue with rounding or imprecision but I was not able to find it and have confirmed all constant values used in the equation.
For your consideration the pictures below are the two parts of the formula I am attempting to addapt. The full paper can be requested at this link: (https://formulieren.kadaster.nl/aanvragen_rdnaptrans) and is free of charge.




And due to its relevance chapter 2.4.1:




Finally my current implementation:
// RD parameters
    private const double k = 0.9999079;
    private const double x0 = 155000;
    private const double y0 = 463000;

    private readonly double phi0 = 52.156161.ToRadians(); // Convert degrees to radians
    private readonly double lambda0 = 5.387639.ToRadians(); // Convert degrees to radians
    private const double R = 6369347.914861309;  // Radius of the Earth in meters
    private readonly double epsilon = 0.000000001.ToRadians();

    // Bessel ellipsoid parameters
    private const double a = 6377397.155;
    private const double f = 1 / 299.1528128;
    private readonly double e = Math.Sqrt(f * (2 - f));

    private Point ParseLocationFromMessage(int xRD, int yRD)
    {
        // Inverse oblique stereographic projection from RD to sphere
        double r = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(xRD - x0, 2) + Math.Pow(yRD - y0, 2));
        double sinAlpha = (xRD - x0) / r;
        double cosAlpha = (yRD - y0) / r;
        double psi = 2 * Math.Atan(r / (2 * k * R));


        //Try cos/sin alpha cos / sin
        double xBar, yBar, zBar;
        if (xRD != x0 || yRD != y0)
        {
            xBar = Math.Cos(phi0) * Math.Cos(psi) - cosAlpha * Math.Sin(phi0) * Math.Sin(psi);
            yBar = sinAlpha * Math.Sin(psi);
            zBar = cosAlpha * Math.Cos(phi0) * Math.Sin(psi) + Math.Sin(phi0) * Math.Cos(psi);
        }
        else
        {
            xBar = Math.Cos(phi0);
            yBar = 0;
            zBar = Math.Sin(phi0);
        }

        double latitude = Math.Asin(zBar);
        double longitude;
        if (xBar > 0)
        {
            longitude = lambda0 + Math.Atan(yBar / xBar);
        }
        else if (xBar < 0 && xRD >= x0)
        {
            longitude = lambda0 + Math.Atan(yBar / xBar) + 180.0.ToRadians();
        }
        else if (xBar < 0 && xRD < x0)
        {
            longitude = lambda0 + Math.Atan(yBar / xBar) - 180.0.ToRadians();
        }
        else if (xBar == 0 && xRD > x0)
        {
            longitude = lambda0 + 90.0.ToRadians();
        }
        else if (xBar == 0 && xRD < x0)
        {
            longitude = lambda0 - 90.0.ToRadians();
        }
        else
        {
            longitude = lambda0;
        }

        double n = Math.Sqrt(1 + (Math.Pow(e, 2) * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi0), 4) / (1 - Math.Pow(e, 2))));
        double Rn = a / Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(e, 2) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(phi0), 2));
        double Rm = Rn * (1 - Math.Pow(e, 2)) / 1 - Math.Pow(e, 2) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(phi0), 2);
        double largePhi0 = Math.Atan(Math.Sqrt(Rm) / Math.Sqrt(Rn) * Math.Tan(phi0));
        double w0 = Math.Log(Math.Tan((largePhi0 + 90.0.ToRadians()) / 2));
        double q0 = Math.Log(Math.Tan((phi0 + 90.0.ToRadians()) / 2)) - (e / 2 * Math.Log(1 + e * Math.Sin(phi0) / (1 - e * Math.Sin(phi0))));
        double m = w0 - n * q0;
        double w = Math.Log(Math.Tan((latitude + 90.0.ToRadians()) / 2));
        double q = (w - m) / n;

        double phi_i = 0;
        double phi_i_next = 0;
        while (Math.Abs(phi_i_next - phi_i) < epsilon)
        {
            phi_i = phi_i_next;

            if (latitude == -90.0.ToRadians() || latitude == 90.0.ToRadians())
            {
                phi_i_next = latitude;
            }
            else if (-90.0.ToRadians() < latitude && latitude < 90.0.ToRadians())
            {
                phi_i_next = 2 * Math.Atan(Math.Exp(q + e / 2 * Math.Log((1 + e * Math.Sin(phi_i)) / (1 - e * Math.Sin(phi_i))))) - 90.0.ToRadians();
            }
        }

        double lambda_n = ((longitude - lambda0) / n) + lambda0;
        double lambda_wrapped = lambda_n.ToDegrees() % 360;
        if (lambda_wrapped > 180) lambda_wrapped -= 360;
        else if (lambda_wrapped <= -180) lambda_wrapped += 360;

        double latitudeFinal = phi_i_next.ToDegrees();
        double longitudeFinal = lambda_wrapped;
        Point point = new Point(new Coordinate(latitudeFinal, longitudeFinal));
        Console.WriteLine(point.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
        return point;
    }

Any suggestion as to where I may be wrong or imprecise or inaccurate or all three at the same time are very welcome. Thank you!

Why not using existing implementations? The code smells (90.0.ToRadians(), epsilon to radians???). Log different steps and intermediate results: usually you should see where the numbers are out of scale. And check your assumption of the inverse functions (the domains).
